# Convert 64 bits array into Int64 or ulong C#

Tags: c#, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, typeconverter, bitarray

I have an int array of bits (length always 64) like:

```
1110000100000110111001000001110010011000110011111100001011100100
```

and I want to write it in one `Int64` (or ulong?) variable. How to do it?

I tried to create a `BitArray` and then get `int`, but it throws `System.ArgumentException`, on CopyTo line:

```
private static Int64 GetIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray) {
    var array = new Int64[1];
    bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return array[0];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because as mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx),

> The specified array must be of a compatible type. Only bool, int, and byte types of arrays are supported.

So you could do something like this: (not tested)

```
private static long GetIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
{
    var array = new byte[8];
    bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(array, 0);
}
```

Looking at the implementation of `BitArray.CopyTo`, it would be faster to copy the bits into an `int[]` (and then build the `long` from its two halves), that could look something like this: (also not tested)

```
private static long GetIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
{
    var array = new int[2];
    bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return (uint)array[0] + ((long)(uint)array[1] << 32);
}
```

Casts to `uint` are to prevent sign-extension.

Comment: Great! You make my day! Solved.